# File Browser and Plotting in same Window

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, user-interface, pysimplegui

I had done a code for browsing a CSV file with the help of PySimpleGUI and plotting the graph on matplotlib. Both come out on different windows. Is there any way that I can embed the matplotlib chart onto the same window as the File browsing window? The code that I did is as follows :

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import PySimpleGUI as sg
filename = sg.popup_get_file("Choose a file: ", file_types=(("ALL CSV Files", "*.csv"), ("ALLFiles", "*.*") ))
ds = pd.read_csv(filename)
print(ds.describe())
print(plt.plot(ds))
plt.xlabel('Milliseconds')
plt.ylabel('Percentage of score')
plt.grid()
plt.savefig(r"C:\Users\Vatsan\Documents\Fanuc\Result.jpeg")    #To save the plot as a jpeg file
plt.show()
```

Also I need to include another file explorer for CSV and its plotting in the same window combined with the previous one. Please help me out with a possible solution

Comment: There're 16 scripts starts with `Demo_Matplotlib_` in https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/tree/master/DemoPrograms

Comment: That didn't help me out! Is there a code solution for this in order to merge these two in a same window?

Comment: I don't have solution for you if you cannot find it there.